# Cleaning up web results after SEO spam attack

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, spam, negative-seo

A while ago my Wordpress-based personal site was hacked with SEO spam. I've since cleaned it up (removed and reinstalled wordpress, manually checked through all files, manually checked database entries). The scan at https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ now shows the website to be OK (before cleaning, it showed that there was SEO spam). The Sucuri and Wordfence plugins indicate that the site is clean. So I'm pretty confident that I've cleaned the website completely.

Now, the problem I face is that the Google results for the site still show lots of SEO spam, which obviously doesn't look very good. This is the same for DuckDuckGo and possibly other search engines. How do I go about cleaning that up? Are there any active steps I can take to do that, or do I just have to wait for their crawlers to recrawl the site and update the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you return a 404 or a 410 for deleted pages. Then resubmit a `sitemap.xml` with all the links/URLs of the website before the SEO attack using dummy recent `lastmod` values. Make sure your are not blocking access to those URLS in your `robots.txt`.

Then, be patient.

Answer (score 1):

Re-submit the sitemap and... wait.
Also, the most effective way to "stimulate" Google to re-visit and re-index is through new links from other websites to the pages that need to be spidered.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Fetch as Google" function in Google Webmaster tools and then click on "Submit to index" and then select "Crawl this URL and its direct links".

This should expedite the re-crawl of those specific pages.